# correct OJDBC jar file version

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm trying to use latest hibernate 5.2.9 to check the new functionality and performance for upgrading my project from 4.2.1.

How to choose the respective `ojdbc` jar file to import? Currently we are using   `Oracle 11g`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ojdbc6` works fine with `Oracle 11g` for me.

If you are using Maven you can use this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: what was the hibernate version which you used ?

Comment: It's hibernate `5.1.3`.